# IndexError: string index out of range keep getting this can't understand how to fix it

Tags: python, string, for-loop, while-loop

```py
    while length > 2:

        if s[i].isalpha():
            i += 1
            i1 = i
            length -= 1

        elif s[i].isdigit():
            if int(s[i]) == 0:
                return False

        if s[i].isalpha():
            continue

        else:
            while s[i].isdigit():
                if s[i1].isalpha(): #erorr stage
                    return False

                i1 += 1
            return False

    length -= 1
    valid += 1
```

I can't seem to understand how to fix my string check length.
This function checks if a string contains digits at its end and if so it should also check if there are no more letters after those digits.

I expect to receive `False` if there are `isalpha` after the digit but the string gets out of bounds before the while loop can finish.

Comment: You use `i1` in `if s[i1].isalpha():` and then increment it. If your string ends in digits, then the loop `while s[i].isdigit():` will "run off the end of the string".

Comment: ohhh ok thank you I understand now I added another condition to the while loop of len(s) > i1

Answer (score 0):

check if i < len(s) along with s[i].isdigit()in the while loop,
while i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).